# excel macro, need an algorithm to compare two lists

Tags: excel, algorithm, vba

I need to make a macro to compare two columns looking for duplicate cells.

I'm currently using this simple double for loop algorithm

```
for i = 0 To ColumnASize
   Cell1 = Sheet.getCellByPosition(0,i)

   for j = 0 to ColumnBSi
   Cell2 = Sheet.getCellByPosition(1,j)

   ' Comparison happens here

   Next j
Next i
```

However, as I have 1000+ items in each column this algorithm is quite slow and inefficient. Does anyone here know/have an idea for a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Are the rows ordered in some way?

Comment: Need a bit more context around what's happening in the comparison. Can you post a bit more code?

Comment: No they are not. I am just comparing two strings (can be anything)

Comment: Take a string from column A, then search all of Column B to see if there is an identical string

Comment: Use VBA arrays instead of referencing the worksheet cells: arrColA = "ColA range"; arrColB = "ColB range".  Then loop through the first array and use the Match worksheet function on the 2nd (or loop through the 2nd doing the comparison).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that no string in col A is equal to any string in col B, then your existing algorithm is order n^2. You may be able to improve that by the following:

1) Sort col A or a copy of it (order nlogn)

2)Sort col B or a copy of it (order nlogn)

3) Look for duplicates by list traversal, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993655/find-common-elements-in-2-sorted-arrays) previous answer (order n).

That should give you an order nlogn solution and I don't think you can do much better than that.