# Fast vector element comparison

Tags: c++

I want to compare elements of vectors filled with integers to look if 
for elements with same values (and count them).

So for example, if `a[i]==x`, is there a `b[j]==x` ?

The first implementation that came to mind, is the most simple one of course:

```
for (int i=0; i < a.size(); i++) {
  for (int j=0; j < b.size(); j++) {
    if (a[i]==b[j]) {counter++;}
  }
```

This is way to slow for larger vectors. 
I have thought of an alternating algorithm, but I'm to unskilled to implement 
it right, so here it is, what I've got yet and my problem:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      if (b[j] >= a[i]) {
        counter++;
        for (int k = i + 1; k < n; k++) {
          if (a[k] >= b[j+1]) {
            counter++;
            for (int l = k + 1; l < m; l++) {
              if (b[l] >= a[k]) {
                counter++;
                ....
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The flow is that I start comparing the first element of `a` with the elements of `b`. When I have a hit, i jump to vector `b` and compare its next element with the elements of `a` that come after the element of `a` I was comparing with before. (Since the elements of `a` and `b` are stored in ascending order, once the element of `b` I'm comparing with is bigger than the element of `a` I change vector on >= not ==)

This should be easy to do with a function that is calling itself, I think.
But I can't wrap my head around it.

I hope somebody can even understand what I'm trying to do, but I can't explain it better at the moment. In theory, I think this should be way faster for vectors in ascending order, since you only have to do N comparisons (N being the size of the larger vector) instead of `N*M`.

Comment: I think it'd make sense to tackle this algorithmically rather than by trying to optimize a loop. For example, sorting the arrays could lead to considerable optimizations. Brute-force comparing seems like the least elegant way to solve this. How large are these arrays, typically?

Comment: The size of the vectors is up to around a million

Comment: Use an `unordered_map`.

Comment: The most important question here is whether vectors are *sorted* or not. And you only mention this in passing somewhere in the middle of your question. So, once again: when they are given to you, are these two vectors *already sorted* or not?

Comment: yes they are sorted in ascending order

Comment: My take on it would be sorting both vectors, then using something like `memcmp` on the underlying data (that is, only if `std::is_pod<vector::value_type>::value` is true).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is variation of the classic problem of merging two sorted vectors.

If the vectors are sorted, the all you need to do is perform an incremental *linear* search of sequential elements of vector `a` in vector `b`. Each search in `b` begins where the previous search left off. This approach will take `O(a.size() + b.size())` comparisons.

```
int count = 0;

int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
  for (; j < b.size() && b[j] <= a[i]; ++j)
    if (b[j] == a[i])
      ++count;
```

If you look closely, you'll see that this is exactly the same algorithm as in @Anedar's answer, just expressed from a "different vantage point".

However, if these two vectors have significantly different length (say, `a` is much shorter than `b`) then it might make sense to take sequential elements of `a` and do a *binary* search in `b`. Again, each search in `b` works "to the right" from the previously found element of `b`. This approach will take `O(a.size() * log b.size())` comparisons.

If `a.size() ~ b.size()` then `O(a.size() + b.size())` is better than `O(a.size() * log b.size())`. But if `a.size() << b.size()`, then it's the other way around.

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth answer (yes I see its the same as @Anedar's).

The problem is, that there is no definition about the relation between sizes. It can be 1:1 in one iteration, 1:1000000 in the next one. So I have to find a middle point. Or use a threshold to choose between binary search and linear search...

Comment: @Fl.pf.: In theory, you can "blend" these two approaches as I describe here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12993740/187690. But in real life a simple threshold might indeed be perfectly sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Since you stated that the elements are stored in order, you could do something like this:

```
int i=0;
int j=0;

while(i< a.size() && j<b.size()){
  if(a[i]==b[j]){
    ++counter;
    ++i;
    ++j;
  }else if(a[i]<b[j]){
    ++i;
  }else{
    ++j;
  }
}
```

Comment: So easy, yet so effective. Thank you very much, that did the trick! (Its still pretty slow, but works for now ;))

Comment: Yes but the worst case complexity is still N*M. Suppose that A contains 1000000 values and B only one but somewhere to the end. So you have to check all values of A one by one until reaching the last one. Not efficient.

Comment: @BajMile sry, but its only O(N+M), as AnT stated in his (more elegant but similar) solution. You can see it like this: in every iteration either `i` or `j` is increased by 1, so in the worst case you end up with `i=N` and `j=M` with no match at all (because that would result in both beeing increased at the same time), which needs exactly `N+M` increases with `2*(N+M)` comparisons.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Maybe the average complexity is proportional to O(N+M) but I think it is still inefficient in some marginal cases. You have bug in the above code - first ++i should be removed if you want to count the repetitions in the first buffer too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not required to use the vector you can use std::multiset,  as container for the values in both sets.

This std::multiset container allows to insert duplicating values and in the same time values are ordered. You can get the number of the elements with std::multiset::count.

One check will be performed in O(logN) complexity, to check if all values from B are contained in A and the counts of repetition the complexity is M(logN) in the worst case. Same can be achieved with std::map but sets takes less memory than maps and are simpler to use.

If a value is in set B more than once only one check can be made in set A.

Comment: But the OP has *two separate* sets of data. That's given. How do you propose to solve this problem in `O(log N)` with "multisets"? What multisets specifically?   One multiset or two multisets? If you simply use two miltisets instead of two vectors, then no, you will not be able to solve on `O(log N)`.

Comment: O(log N) is one check in A. To check all values from B you need to make MO(log N). But if B is also set M is reduced to the unique values number.

Comment: But one check in a sorted vector is also `O(log N)`, which means that checking everything is `O(M * log N)` in sorted vectors. But two sorted sequences can be checked in `O(M + N)`, as shown in other answers, which is better than `O(M * log N)` when `M` and `N` are close. This applies identically to sets and sorted vectors. In fact, there's absolutely no difference between a set and sorted vector in this context. Which is why it is unclear to me what specifically is the point you are trying to make.