# Using for loop and find instead of set_intersection?

Tags: c++, stl, intersection

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400157/the-intersection-of-two-sorted-arrays) suggests using `std::set_intersection` to find the intersection of two arrays. Wouldn't using `std::find` work just as well?

```
int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int b[5] = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    if (std::find(b, b+5, a[i])!=b+5)
        std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Does `std::set_intersection` basically do the same thing? Or maybe it uses a more efficient algorithm? I think the complexity of above is O(n^2) if `std::find` takes O(n) time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all (or at least almost all) of your standard-library-complexity questions, [a good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) can answer this for you.
In particular we get that `std::find` performs `At most last - first applications of the predicate` (`operator<` in this case) where first and last define your range to be searched.
We also get that `std::set_intersection` performs `At most 2·(N1+N2-1) comparisons, where N1 = std::distance(first1, last1) and N2 = std::distance(first2, last2)`.

This means that your loop performs at most `N1 * N2` applications of `operator<`, which in this case is 25.  `std::set_intersection` would use at most 18.

So, the two methods would "work just as well" in the sense that they give the same answer, but `std::set_intersection` would take less comparisons to do it.

Answer (score 0):

std::set is an ordered collection. There are faster methods (linear) for such collections (think mergesort).

Answer (score 0):

`std::set::find` takes `O(lg n)`, it's a binary search. So using a for loop together with find takes `O(n lg n)`. `std::set_intersection` takes linear time: align the two sets to find their intersection (similar to the merge operation of mergesort).

Comment: `std::find` does not do a binary search since there is no way for it to know _a priori_ that the input range is sorted, so it takes linear time.

Comment: sets have their own version of find. Edited to point that out.

Comment: There aren't any set objects here, we have arrays.  And even if we did have sets, using `std::find` with iterators from a set isn't guaranteed to take `O(log n)`.  Only using `std::set<...>::find` is guaranteed to do that.

Comment: There is mention to set_intersection and arrays in OP are sorted. Link to suggested answer talks about sorted sets as well.

Comment: `std::set_intersection` doesn't just work on sets, it works on any sorted range, of which `std::set` is one example.  This doesn't change the fact that your `std::find` can only be guaranteed to take linear time.  Unless when you say `std::find` you mean `std::set::find`, your answer has an error.