# Can set_intersection be used with hash_set in C++?

Tags: c++, stl, set, intersection, hashset

I am calculating intersection, union and differences of sets.
I have a typedef of my set type:

```
typedef set<node_type> node_set;
```

When it is replaced with

```
typedef hash_set<node_type> node_set;
```

The results are different. It's a complicated program, and before I start debugging - am I doing it right? When I use functions like this:

```
set_intersection(v_higher.begin(), v_higher.end(), neighbors[w].begin(), neighbors[w].end(), 
            insert_iterator<node_set>(tmp1, tmp1.begin()));
```

- should they work seamlessly with both set and hash_set?

Comment: hash_set is not part of Standard C++, so it is difficult to say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think so.

[One of the pre-condition of `set_intersection`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set_intersection.html) is:

- `[first1, last1)` is **ordered in ascending order** according to `operator<`. That is, for every pair of iterators `i` and `j` in `[first1, last1)` such that `i` precedes `j`, `*j < *i` is false.

The `hash_set` (and `unordered_set`) is unordered, so the ordered condition cannot be satisfied.

See [tr1::unordered_set union and intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896155/c-tr1unordered-set-union-and-intersection) on how to intersect `unordered_set`s.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go with no. Keep in mind `hash_set` isn't standard C++ and never will be, it's an older extension that's no longer supported. The newer "hash maps" are called `unordered_set` and `unordered_map`, available in TR1, Boost, and C++0x.

The reason it's a no is that `set_intersection` requires the input data to be sorted. Contrarily, the reason a hash map is so quick is it gives up ordering. This is obviously more pronounced under the name `unordered_set`. So the precondition cannot be reliably met.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use `set_intersection` because `set_intersection` requires that the two sets are ordered (using the same ordering). Hash sets aren't ordered in any way. In C++0x they will in fact be called `unordered_set`.