# How to find the intersection of two std::hash_set in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, std, hashset

Does the STD library provide any function that allows me to find intersection of two std::hash_set?

I tried using `std::set_intersection` but I get assertion error with `Expression: sequence not ordered`, is there any work around this?

```
#include <hash_set>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::hash_set<std::string> h1;
    h1.insert("NoMainDraw");
    h1.insert("NoLight");
    h1.insert("Random");

    std::hash_set<std::string> h2;
    h2.insert("NoLight");

    std::vector<std::string> groupDifference;
    std::set_intersection(h1.cbegin(), h1.cend(),
                          h2.cbegin(), h2.cend(),
                          std::back_inserter(groupDifference));

    for(const std::string& i : groupDifference)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need `set_intersection`, you probably want to use `std::set` instead (and you don't want to use `hash_set` in any case--the standard version is `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: `set_intersection` only works on sorted ranges.

Comment: [tr1::unordered_set union and intersection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896155/tr1unordered-set-union-and-intersection) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to iterate one `map` doing lookups in the other.  There's no Standard-library algo.